# Python: EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, text, python-2.7, compiler-construction, sublimetext2

This may be repeated, but none of the existing answers solved my problem.

So, I'm using `Python 2.7`, and I get this error (title) whenever I try this:

```
number = int(raw_input('Number : '))
```

I tried this in Sublime Text 2, compileronline.com and in codecademy; it fails in the first 2 of this sites. It works on codecademy and in the terminal compiler, but I can't understand exactly why it is failing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The issue here is that Sublime text 2's console doesn't support input.](http://www.bestpythonide.com/python-input-eoferror-in-sublime-text-2.html)

To fix this issue, you can install a package called [SublimeREPL](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). SublimeREPL provides a Python interpreter that takes in input.

And as for compileronline.com, you need to provide input in the "STDIN Input" field on the lower right of the website.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    value = raw_input()
    do_stuff(value) # next line was found 
except (EOFError):
   break #end of file reached
```

This seems to be proper usage of raw_input when dealing with the end of the stream of input from piped input.
[Refer this post](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/eofexceptionrawinput/)