# Line of Python code not working in my game

Tags: python, debugging, command, raw-input, adventure

So this line of code in my Python game is not working:

```
direction=raw_input("What would you like to do?\n")
```

It's supposed to get the player to type in a command either: North, South, East, West, Look, Search, Commands or Inventory. It's coming up with this:

> *Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/khalilismail/Desktop/COMPUTING/Text-based Games/DragonQuest.py", line 173, in 
>       direction=raw_input("What would you like to do?\n")
>   EOFError: EOF when reading a line*

**Please help**

Here is the stack of code surrounding this:
while game==on:

```
while place==town:

    direction=raw_input("What would you like to do?\n")

    if direction=="west":
        if "iron ore" and "wood" and "3 Gold Pieces" in items:
            print "The blacksmith greets you, and you tell him that you have the items and money he requires, you also give him the saw to make up for some of the difference, he then forges you a battleaxe and wishes you luck on the rest of your quest"
            items.remove ("saw")
            items.remove ("3 Gold Pieces")
            items.remove ("iron ore")
            items.remove ("wood")
            items.append ("battleaxe")
```

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the lines of code around this line?

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: what do you enter when the error happens? Also where are you running it?

Comment: are you running this using an online interpreter by any chance?

Comment: An `EOFError` will be raised if you press `Ctrl` + `D`.

Comment: Are you using Sublime Text? Some people has had some trouble with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758782/python-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line

Comment: Aside: your `if "iron ore" and "wood"` etc. line doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Addition to aside: you should do `all(i in items for i in ("iron ore", "wood", "3 Gold Pieces"))` instead.

Comment: I'm using Atom text editor in Python

Comment: So try running your program from the command line instead of within Atom. If `raw_input()` now works as expected, then you know it's an issue with input in Atom similar to the one @RicardoBurillo mentioned with Sublime Text.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, some editors don't support input (including Atom). Here are some options you can overcome this:

1. Set the direction variable by hard-coding it while debugging (don't forget to remove it after debugging)
2. Change your editor (keep in mind that Sublime also has the same problem, but this has a workaround - [Sublime Text 2 console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input); Notepad++ however doesn't have this problem when running code through command line).

You could also try and remove the newline '\n' from the raw_input string to test if it works.