# python raw_input after sys.stdin read

Tags: python, stdin, eof, raw-input

I've got problem with following lines. First I read from STDIN (one line from a Java program STOUT), then I would like to read from prompt in the Python (2.7) program.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    c = line.split()
    break;
//
// do stuff
//
val = raw_input()
print(val)
```

which return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    val = raw_input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How to stop reading from STDIN and read from the prompt?
Thanks, 
Nicolas

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758782/python-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line

Comment: Use `raw_input` to read one line from stdin as well.

Comment: How to use `raw_input` with stdin ?

Comment: see if the following works: `c = raw_input().split(); val = raw_input()`

Comment: `raw_input()` read on stdin but I get same error.

Comment: I've asked this very same question except using Java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316100/java-read-file-from-stdin-then-prompt-user-for-input). I surmise the answer to one will be useful to the other but I start thinking it is not possible at all...