# tcs xplore hands on problem python 2023 class city Compile this code shows line 74, in <module> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python

TCS python hands-on problem 2023

```
def firt(n):
    return n[0] 

def sort(lst):
    return sorted(lst,key=firt)

class City:
    def __init__(self,city_id,state_name,city_name,covidbeds,avlblcovbeds,ventilbeds,avlblventilbeds):
      self.city_id = city_id
      self.state_name = state_name
      self.city_name = city_name
      self.covidbeds = covidbeds
      self.avlblcovbeds = avlblcovbeds
      self.ventilbeds = ventilbeds
      self.avlblventilbeds = avlblventilbeds
    
  
class CovBedsAnalysis:
  def __init__(self,analysis_name,city_list):
    self.analysis_name = analysis_name
    self.city_list = city_list
    
  def get_StateWiseAvlblBedStats(self):
    self.state = []
    self.list_of_state = []
    for city in self.city_list:
        if city.state_name not in self.state:
          self.state.append(city.state_name)
          self.list_of_state.append([city.state_name,city.avlblcovbeds,city.avlblventilbeds])
        else:
          for st in self.list_of_state:
            if(st[0] == city.state_name):
              st[1] += city.avlblcovbeds
              st[2] += city.avlblventilbeds
    out_list = []
    for statee in self.list_of_state:
      out_list.append(tuple(statee))
    return sort(out_list)

  def count_no_city(self,state_nm):
      count = 0
      for city in self.city_list:
          if city.state_name == state_nm:
              count = count + 1
      return count

  def get_CiitesWithMoreThanAvgOccupiedbeds(self,state_nm):
    avgCobBed = 0
    avgVetBed = 0
    out_dict = {}
    for stt in self.list_of_state:
      if(stt[0] == state_nm):
        avgCobBed = stt[1]/self.count_no_city(state_nm)
        avgVetBed = stt[2]/self.count_no_city(state_nm)
        break
    for city in self.city_list:
      if city.state_name == state_nm:
        if city.avlblcovbeds > avgCobBed and city.avlblventilbeds > avgVetBed:
          out_dict[city.city_name] = (city.covidbeds - city.avlblcovbeds, city.ventilbeds - city.avlblventilbeds)
    return out_dict
              
        

          
    
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  t = int(input())
  list_of_city = []
  while t > 0:
    city_id = int(input())
    state_name = input()
    city_name = input()
    covidbeds = int(input())
    avlblcovbeds = int(input())
    ventilbeds = int(input())
    avlblventilbeds = int(input())
    temp_obj_city = City(city_id,state_name,city_name,covidbeds,avlblcovbeds,ventilbeds,avlblventilbeds)
    list_of_city.append(temp_obj_city)
    t = t - 1
  st = input()
  analysis = CovBedsAnalysis("name",list_of_city)
  state_list_analysis = analysis.get_StateWiseAvlblBedStats()
  for statet in state_list_analysis:
        print(str(statet[0])+" "+str(statet[1])+" "+ str(statet[2]))

  mor_than_avg = analysis.get_CiitesWithMoreThanAvgOccupiedbeds(st)

  if(len(mor_than_avg) == 0):
    print("No city available")
  else:
    for city,lst in mor_than_avg.items():
      print(city+" "+str(lst[0])+" "+str(lst[1]))
```

Compile this code it's shows Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/2199945_1680193329/22896116737.py", line 74, in  EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Input:
5
101
Delhi
Delhi
100000
20000
5000
2000
102
Telangana
Hyderabad
200000
40000
1000
500
103
Telangana
Warangal
100000
30000
2000
1000
104
AndhraPradesh
Vijayawada
800000
300000
30000
2500
105
AndhraPradesh
Vizag
500000
100000
6000
1000
AndhraPradesh

Output:

AndhraPradesh 400000 3500
Delhi 20000 2000
Telangana 70000 1500
Vijayawada 500000 27500

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675925/eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line?rq=2) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758782/python-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line?rq=2)  solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is some values missing on their input values which is raising those errors, We can't do anything about it. Do write about the problem to them hope they will fix asap.